# Elasticsearch Scroll API query to return specific range of data

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Can anyone please help me on Elastic search Scroll API.

Elastic Search is limited to search record for up to 10,000 records so if we need to fetch data more than this limit we need to use Scroll API.

I am not able to find any provision where I can fetch records from specific range.. like I am on any page I need to get 100 records only with Scroll API.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: As the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scroll.html) say: _"Scrolling allows us to do an initial search and to keep pulling batches of results from Elasticsearch until there are no more results left. It’s a bit like a cursor in a traditional database."_ - which is why you can't ask for specific ranges.

Comment: Can't do that with elasticsearch because of the distributed nature. 
If the count of pages are relatively small and you know that they wouldn't extend beyond a certain figure, then you can also increase the 10,000 limit of offset+limit for results. 
Read: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html

Comment: Thanks @ArchitSaxena & stuartd. I have a very big data like in one day it can be up to 25,000 and when we do search with some date range it would be in lacks and then I need to do scroll search but i am not able to found any specific and optimized logic to do pagination with scroll api as i need a range of data to show according to clicked page.